# Add HTML until requirement is reached

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to create a form where I need the user to add at least 3 years of address data. However i'm having issues with adding and removing fields depending on if the user enters the correct amount of years.

For example, adding 1 into the year box 3 times below works fine. I get 3 sets of the address fields, however if the user then changes the last set to 2 years, a 4th is added, when really nothing should happen.

There also seems to be a glitch if I then change the second address to 2/3 years it removes the ones below as it should, but changing it back to 1 year doesn't re-add these additional fields.

Hope this makes sense, I just need a hand getting this logic working as I can't figure it out. Don't comment on the functions I have created to generate the HTML, this is just to get this job done, please stick the subject.

**Note: Ignore the bottom 3 functions, these are not the issue and not my priority.**

```js
let addresses = {
  '#years_at_address_0': { /* The default one */
    elm: document.querySelector('#years_at_address_0'),
    value: 0,
    parent: '#previousAddress',
    added: false
  }
};

function setupAddressChecking(watch)
{

    if (addresses[watch] === undefined) {
        addresses[watch] = {
            elm: document.querySelector(watch),
            value: 0,
            parent: '#previousAddress' + (Object.keys(addresses).length > 0 ? Object.keys(addresses).length : ''),
            added: false
        };
    }
    let count = Object.keys(addresses).length;

    addresses[watch].elm.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (this.value && addresses[watch].value !== this.value) {

            addresses[watch].value = parseInt(this.value);

            if (calculateYears() && !addresses[watch].added) {
                document.querySelector('#yearsAdditional').appendChild(createNewAddress());
                addresses[watch].added = true;

                setupAddressChecking('#years_at_address_'+count);
            }
        }
    });

}

function calculateYears()
{
    let count = 0;
    let remove = false;

    const keys = Object.keys(addresses);

    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

        let current = addresses[keys[i]];

        if (count > 3) {
            remove = true;
            current.added = false;
            document.querySelector(current.parent).parentNode.removeChild(document.querySelector(current.parent));
            delete addresses[keys[i]];
        }

        count += current.value;

    }

    if (count === 3) {
        return false;
    }

    return !remove;
}

function createNewAddress()
{
    let count = Object.keys(addresses).length;

    return createHTML({

        0: { elm: createElement('div', {'id': 'previousAddress' + count}), root: null },

        1: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 0 },
        2: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 1},
        3: { elm: createElement('label', {'for': 'previous_address', 'text': 'Address'}), root: 2},
        4: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 1},
        5: { elm: createElement('textarea', {
            'cols': 40,
            'id': 'previous_address' + count,
            'name': 'finprop_previous_address',
            'placeholder': 'Previous Address',
            'rows': 4
        }), root: 4},
        6: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 1},

        7: { elm: createElement('div', { 'id': 'previous_row_postcode' + count}), root: 0 },
        8: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 7 },
        9: { elm: createElement('label', {'for': 'previous_postcode', 'text': 'Postcode *'}), root: 8 },
        10: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 7 },
        11: { elm: createElement('input', {
            'id': 'previous_postcode' + count,
            'name': 'previous_postcode',
            'placeholder': 'Postcode',
            'type': 'text',
            'maxlength': 8
        }), root: 10 },
        12: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 7 },

        13: { elm: createElement('div', {'id': 'row_months_years_at_address' + count}), root: 0 },
        14: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 13 },
        15: { elm: createElement('label', {'for': 'years_at_address_' + count, 'text': 'How long at address *'}), root: 14 },
        16: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 13 },
        17: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 16 },
        18: { elm: createElement('input', {
            'id': 'years_at_address_'  + count,
            'maxlength': 2,
            'min': 0,
            'name': 'finprop_years_at_address',
            'placeholder': 'Years',
            'size': 4,
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'years_at_address'
        }), root: 17 },
        19: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 16 },
        20: { elm: createElement('input', {
            'id': 'months_at_address_' + count,
            'maxlength': 2,
            'min': 0,
            'name': 'finprop_months_at_address',
            'placeholder': 'Months',
            'size': 4,
            'type': 'text'
        }), root: 19 },
        21: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 13 }

    })[0].elm;

}

function createHTML(elements)
{
    let keys = Object.keys(elements);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (elements[keys[i]].root === null || elements[keys[i]].root === i) {
            continue;
        }
        elements[elements[keys[i]].root].elm.appendChild(elements[keys[i]].elm);
    }
    return elements;
}

function createElement(type, options)
{
    let elm = document.createElement(type);
    if (options) {
        for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(options).length; i++) {
            let key = Object.keys(options)[i];
            if (key === 'text') {
                elm.innerHTML = options[key];
                continue;
            }
            elm.setAttribute(key, options[key]);
        }
    }

    return elm;
}

setupAddressChecking('#years_at_address_0');
```

```css
fieldset > div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>

    <h3>Address Details * denotes a required field</h3>

    <div>
        <div id="previousAddress0">
          <div>
              <div><label for="previous_address0">Address</label></div>
              <div><textarea cols="40" id="previous_address0" name="finprop_previous_address0" placeholder="Previous Address" rows="4"></textarea></div>
              <div></div>
          </div>
          <div id="previous_row_postcode0">
              <div><label for="previous_postcode0">Postcode *</label></div>
              <div><input id="previous_postcode0" name="previous_postcode0" placeholder="Postcode" type="text" maxlength="8">  
              </div>
              <div></div>
          </div>
          <div id="row_months_years_at_address0">
              <div><label for="years_at_address_0">How long at address *</label></div>
              <div>
                  <div><input id="years_at_address_0" maxlength="2" min="0" name="finprop_years_at_address0" placeholder="Years" size="4" type="text" class="years_at_address0"></div>
                  <div><input id="months_at_address_0" maxlength="2" min="0" name="finprop_months_at_address0" placeholder="Months" size="4" type="text"></div>
              </div>
              <div></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="yearsAdditional"></div>


</fieldset>
```

Comment: An object with "numeric" properties starting at zero and that are incremented by one should be a real array.

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration while counting the years you're adding the current box to `count` **after** checking if it's greater than 3. This means that in most situations if the last box is greater than 1, an additional box will be created.

To change this add the current `year` value **before** checking if `count` is greater than 3.

```
    count += current.value;
    if (count > 3) {
        remove = true;
        current.added = false;
        document.querySelector(current.parent).parentNode.removeChild(document.querySelector(current.parent));
        delete addresses[keys[i]];
    }
```

---

### Example:

```js
let addresses = {
  '#years_at_address_0': { /* The default one */
    elm: document.querySelector('#years_at_address_0'),
    value: 0,
    parent: '#previousAddress',
    added: false
  }
};

function setupAddressChecking(watch)
{

    if (addresses[watch] === undefined) {
        addresses[watch] = {
            elm: document.querySelector(watch),
            value: 0,
            parent: '#previousAddress' + (Object.keys(addresses).length > 0 ? Object.keys(addresses).length : ''),
            added: false
        };
    }
    let count = Object.keys(addresses).length;

    addresses[watch].elm.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if (this.value && addresses[watch].value !== this.value) {

            addresses[watch].value = parseInt(this.value);

            if (calculateYears() && !addresses[watch].added) {
                document.querySelector('#yearsAdditional').appendChild(createNewAddress());
                addresses[watch].added = true;

                setupAddressChecking('#years_at_address_'+count);
            }
        }
    });

}

function calculateYears()
{
    let count = 0;
    let remove = false;

    const keys = Object.keys(addresses);

    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

        let current = addresses[keys[i]];
        count += current.value;
        if (count > 3) {
            remove = true;
            current.added = false;
            document.querySelector(current.parent).parentNode.removeChild(document.querySelector(current.parent));
            delete addresses[keys[i]];
        }



    }

    if (count === 3) {
        return false;
    }

    return !remove;
}

function createNewAddress()
{
    let count = Object.keys(addresses).length;

    return createHTML({

        0: { elm: createElement('div', {'id': 'previousAddress' + count}), root: null },

        1: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 0 },
        2: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 1},
        3: { elm: createElement('label', {'for': 'previous_address', 'text': 'Address'}), root: 2},
        4: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 1},
        5: { elm: createElement('textarea', {
            'cols': 40,
            'id': 'previous_address' + count,
            'name': 'finprop_previous_address',
            'placeholder': 'Previous Address',
            'rows': 4
        }), root: 4},
        6: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 1},

        7: { elm: createElement('div', { 'id': 'previous_row_postcode' + count}), root: 0 },
        8: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 7 },
        9: { elm: createElement('label', {'for': 'previous_postcode', 'text': 'Postcode *'}), root: 8 },
        10: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 7 },
        11: { elm: createElement('input', {
            'id': 'previous_postcode' + count,
            'name': 'previous_postcode',
            'placeholder': 'Postcode',
            'type': 'text',
            'maxlength': 8
        }), root: 10 },
        12: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 7 },

        13: { elm: createElement('div', {'id': 'row_months_years_at_address' + count}), root: 0 },
        14: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 13 },
        15: { elm: createElement('label', {'for': 'years_at_address_' + count, 'text': 'How long at address *'}), root: 14 },
        16: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 13 },
        17: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 16 },
        18: { elm: createElement('input', {
            'id': 'years_at_address_'  + count,
            'maxlength': 2,
            'min': 0,
            'name': 'finprop_years_at_address',
            'placeholder': 'Years',
            'size': 4,
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'years_at_address'
        }), root: 17 },
        19: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 16 },
        20: { elm: createElement('input', {
            'id': 'months_at_address_' + count,
            'maxlength': 2,
            'min': 0,
            'name': 'finprop_months_at_address',
            'placeholder': 'Months',
            'size': 4,
            'type': 'text'
        }), root: 19 },
        21: { elm: createElement('div'), root: 13 }

    })[0].elm;

}

function createHTML(elements)
{
    let keys = Object.keys(elements);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (elements[keys[i]].root === null || elements[keys[i]].root === i) {
            continue;
        }
        elements[elements[keys[i]].root].elm.appendChild(elements[keys[i]].elm);
    }
    return elements;
}

function createElement(type, options)
{
    let elm = document.createElement(type);
    if (options) {
        for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(options).length; i++) {
            let key = Object.keys(options)[i];
            if (key === 'text') {
                elm.innerHTML = options[key];
                continue;
            }
            elm.setAttribute(key, options[key]);
        }
    }

    return elm;
}

setupAddressChecking('#years_at_address_0');
```

```css
fieldset > div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>

    <h3>Address Details * denotes a required field</h3>

    <div>
        <div id="previousAddress0">
          <div>
              <div><label for="previous_address0">Address</label></div>
              <div><textarea cols="40" id="previous_address0" name="finprop_previous_address0" placeholder="Previous Address" rows="4"></textarea></div>
              <div></div>
          </div>
          <div id="previous_row_postcode0">
              <div><label for="previous_postcode0">Postcode *</label></div>
              <div><input id="previous_postcode0" name="previous_postcode0" placeholder="Postcode" type="text" maxlength="8">  
              </div>
              <div></div>
          </div>
          <div id="row_months_years_at_address0">
              <div><label for="years_at_address_0">How long at address *</label></div>
              <div>
                  <div><input id="years_at_address_0" maxlength="2" min="0" name="finprop_years_at_address0" placeholder="Years" size="4" type="text" class="years_at_address0"></div>
                  <div><input id="months_at_address_0" maxlength="2" min="0" name="finprop_months_at_address0" placeholder="Months" size="4" type="text"></div>
              </div>
              <div></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="yearsAdditional"></div>


</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Hint (logic)

Multiply HTML with a loop. Within the loop is your desired HTML. Set an if statement before the loop.

Make a reset with `el.innerHTML = ""`.

#### Example

```js
let result = document.getElementById("result");


function createHTML(n, text) {
  let res = "";
  if (n < 4) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
      // Use your own HTML
      res += `<form id="form-${i + 2}">`;
      res += `<ul>`;
      res += `<li><textarea></textarea></li>`;
      res += `<li><span>Year</span><input class="year" type="text"></li>`;
      res += `<li><span>Month</span><input class="month" type="text"></li>`;
      res += `</ul>`;
      res += `</form>`;
    }
  }

  return res;
}

function multiply(n) {
  result.innerHTML = "";
  result.innerHTML = createHTML(n, "Heading");
}
```

```css
form[id^="form-"] {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 15px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

form[id^="form-"] ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- First form -->
<form id="form-1">
  <ul>
    <li><textarea></textarea></li>
    <li><span>Year</span><input class="year" type="text"></li>
    <li><span>Month</span><input class="month" type="text"></li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" onkeyup="multiply(this.value)">
</form>


<div id="result"></div>
```